# Store values of navigation stack in a dictionary iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, nsmutabledictionary

I need to track the users navigation flow and store it in a `Dictionary`, Every time user visits any screen in my app. I can see the navigation stack in my console output by using code

navigationController?.viewControllers

But don't know, how to store this in dictionary.

Please help

Comment: What is the purpose of using dict.?

Comment: do you need to get the name of the vc for each 1 ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan:Yes I need the name of every view controller

Comment: @MahendraGP :Actually the purpose of capturing the name of VC is for storing users navigation in a txt file and send to server.For that I will initially add th flow indictionary and then i will write this to a text file

Comment: Maybe you could add a small example to your question like if the user visits vc1 then goes to vc2 and back again to vc1, what do you expect to have in your dictionary then?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson:it will be better,if i am able to form string VC1_VC2_VC1 and store  it inside dictionary for key " navigationstack"

Comment: What else will you have in the dictionary, looks to me like an array would be a better solution. And please add any examples/further clarification to your question rather than posting them as questions. Makes it easier for everyone to understand what your asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the names of all `UIViewControllers` on `navigationStack` using,

```
let controllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.compactMap({ String(describing: type(of: $0.self)) }).joined(separator: "_")
print(controllers) //Output: "VC1_VC2_VC3"
```

You can store the `controllers` string in your file.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps to get viewcontroller. Follow this and store into global dictionary using singleton.

**Global Function:**

```
public func storeCurrentViewController(_ currentFile: String = #file)
{
    let className = currentFile.components(separatedBy: "/").last ?? ""
    let classNameArr = className.components(separatedBy: ".")
    print("\n\n--> CurrentViewController:  \(classNameArr[0])")

    //*********** Use dictionary and do your logics

}
```

**Function Call:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    storeCurrentViewController()
}
```

Comment: Hope this helps. Store into dictionary as you required.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
                for( int i=0;i<[viewControllers count];i++){
                    id obj=[viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];    
                    NSLog(@"%@",[obj classNameForClass:[obj class]]);
}
```

Not sure if this works. Give a try...